# Перезапуск функции Function_1 после подготовки конечного файла к выгрузке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице присутствует форма Form_1. Для выбора доступных вариантов фильтрации данных из базы через Ajax делается выборка (функция Function_1). Результат передается в Function_2 где "на лету" также через Ajax формируется файл доступный для загрузки пользователем. Выгрузка файла доступна через window.open или window.location.
После выгрузки файла для нового сеанса работы с формой необходимо перезапустить Function_1, что делается пока что в ручном режиме.
Задача: необходимо перезапустить Function_1 после подготовки конечного файла к выгрузке.

```
<html>
<form id="Form_1"></form>
</html>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

// Load data for Form_1 => Data for searching data in the database
    Function_1 (){
        ..
        $.ajax () {
            ..
            Function_2 (data1); 
        );
    }


// File generation and upload
    Function_2 () {
        ..
        $.ajax () {
            ..
            window.open ('PATH/FILE.PHP'+out_data);
            Function_1 ();
        );
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: проблема не ясна. у ajax есть метод success или complete, в котором можно спокойно запустить функцию и вообще сделать что угодно

Comment: Код выгрузки файла и перезапуска Function_1 установлен в методе success. Благодарю за подсказку. Посмотрю метод complete...

Comment: Метод complete не подходит. Запрос выполнен, а конструкция window.open или window.location, которая используется для формирования и выгрузки конечного файла продолжает свою работу. Весь фокус заключается в том чтобы Function_1 (); была выполнена после завершения работы window.open или window.location